# Reverse UILabel.text value

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I've got a program that I'm finishing up that is a name generator. Right now it takes a random value from 2 separate arrays, concatenates them and displays the result as the label. text -- I want to have a button that reverses the label text (instead of John Doe, it would say Doe John). This is the code I'm using to do this. My thinking is that I use the same values from the arrays and then assign the string to a variable for use later in another method called "reverseNameValue" or something. It's not working :) When I click the "reverse" button, it shows me a different name altogether. Any advice?

```
- (IBAction)generateBName:(id)sender {
int a = arc4random() % 3;
int b = arc4random() % 3;


// populate the array for the names
NSArray *firstNameArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Jacob",
                           @"Ethan",
                           @"Justin", nil];
NSArray *middleNameArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Jose",
                            @"Jeremiah",
                            @"Julian", nil];

// concatenate strings at index of array
NSString *fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [firstNameArray objectAtIndex:a], [middleNameArray objectAtIndex:b]];
NSString *reverseName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [firstNameArray objectAtIndex:b], [middleNameArray objectAtIndex:a]];

// display the newly created first & middle names
reverseNameString = reverseName;
babyname.text = fullName;
```

And the reverse method:

```
- (IBAction)reverseLabel:(id)sender {
babyname.text = reverseNameString;
}
```

Comment: The "reverse" button triggers this method?

Comment: This method is for the "generate" button.. the reverse button will basically show babyname.text = reverseNameString;

Comment: Could you include the code that's run when "reverse" is pressed? Is `reverseNameString` an ivar? Are you compiling with ARC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the line where you set the reverseName string has the names backwards, so it is grabbing a firstname and then a middlename but with reversed indexes. It should be:

```
 NSString *reverseName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [middleNameArray objectAtIndex:b],[firstNameArray objectAtIndex:a]];
```

Comment: Bingo, that's it. (cue d'oh soundbyte). Will "accept" this in 6 minutes when I can :D